# Git clone: increase depth after cloning

Tags: git

There is a very large repo I am working with. For better or worse, even using `git clone --depth=1` yields a few MB. The whole repo exceeds 1GB, and I do not want that much information.

After cloning a repo with `git clone --depth=X` how does one add more depth?

In my case, I initially set the depth to 1. Is there a way to get all of the details up to a depth of 20 without deleting and recloning the repo with the new depth value?

Answer (score 5):

Use

```sh
git fetch --unshallow
```

To convert to a full clone, or

```sh
git fetch --deepen 20
```

To increase to a specific number